# Smarty compare strings

Tags: string, smarty

I am trying to compare to values in smarty:

```
{if $needle == '1'}
// Whatever
{else}
// ..
{/if}
```

`$needle` has the value "0" (string). By calling the site, i never get into the "else" case. Somebody can tell me why?

What i have tried so far:

`$needle` to INT Cast (by `$needle|intval`, `(int) $needle`, `$needle|string_format:"%d"`)
Used `===` and `eq` Operator instead `==`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do something wrong.

If in PHP I have:

```
$smarty->assign('needle', '0'); // needle is string 0
```

and in Smarty I have:

```
{if $needle == '1'}
    // Whatever
{else}
    // ..
{/if}
```

it is working as it should:

```
// ..
```

is being displayed.

If this simple code doesn't work for you, you should add the following code:

```
{$needle|var_dump}
```

before `if` and this will display you value and type.

**You should also make sure that this Smarty template file is executed at all because if it isn't that's why you don't go to else condition.**